# Indirection through ESI and Pointers

Tags: assembly, x86

I am new to the assembly programming(x86 asm with MASM) and was learning about indirection supported by the **ESI** register you just need to place the address into the **ESI** and then use indirection operator and you would be able to access the pointed data.

Q1.In the coding one can use **[esi+4]** but can't use **esi+4**(Results into an error).Why? Because in assembly writing indirection operator([]) explicitly is not necessary and is mainly for the programmer's understanding.

Q2. If I apply indirection to the pointer variables then they don't seem to work. Why is it? Are the pointers only meant to be used as containers.

Eg-

```
mov eax, [esi] ; It sets eax with the value of memory location pointed by esi

mov eax,[ptr4] ; Does not work the same
```

Comment: MASM or some other assembler?

Comment: I am using MASM (Visual studio)

Comment: How did you declare `ptr4` and what is the exact error you get?

Comment: In MASM the square brackets ([]) are actually an addition operator. Only when they surround a register name do they imply indirection.

Comment: Actually I got error with the esi+4 saying invalid use of register. The ptr4 thing does not show up errors but does not seem to work like indirection rather acts as a normal variable

Comment: The x86 doesn't support memory indirect operands and it doesn't support a register plus a constant as a single operand.

Comment: @RossRidge So do you mean that first MASM interprets the square brackets gets to know that it has to do indirection and then follows the instruction?

Comment: What makes you think `mov eax,[ptr4]` doesn't work? It should move the 4 bytes starting at memory address that the label `ptr4` into _EAX_.

Comment: @MichaelPetch My intension was to work on the address formed by the bytes contained by ptr4 like the way it happens with esi

Comment: I'm saying that `[ptr4]` is interpreted is as `0 + ptr4` or just `ptr4` to MASM.

Comment: So `ptr4` is  in fact a memory location holding a 32-bit pointer. You'd have to move the value (pointer in this case) at that address into a temporary register and then dereference it. Like `mov esi,[ptr4]` `mov, eax,[esi]`

Comment: @MichaelPetch So I can't directly work with pointers I would have to necessarily use esi in order to dereference it. So it seems that variables can be moved to their offsets only but no jumping around with indirection that could only be done by registers.

Comment: You can directly work with pointers but in this case `ptr4` is a label (pointer/address) to a pointer. Ross pointed out x86 doesn't support memory indirect operands with a single instruction.

Comment: So how to directly work with a pointer?

Comment: You're programming in assembly. You can't expect every high level language concept to have a direct equivalent. Michael Petch gave an example of how you might work with a "pointer" stored in a "variable" named `ptr4`. Note that pointers and variables are examples of HLL concepts that don't have direct equivalents in assembly. What the code is really doing is loading a 32-bit value from memory whose address is given by another 32-bit value in memory whose address is given by the symbol `ptr4`. This has to be done in two instructions because there isn't one instruction that can do that.

Comment: @RossRidge ,Michael Petch Thanks a lot for your help now I think I have understood the thing since I have come here after c++ so it may be a little difficult for me to get into the flow of assembly. It seems like it is the language with a lots of patches and fixes...

Comment: @HarshulSharma assembly language does not have "lots of patches and fixes". It creates a sequence of processor instructions, in accordance with the syntax rules of the assembler.

Comment: ... and the instruction set of the processor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a quirk of the MASM syntax. The `[`...`]` is auto-inserted around memory address labels. In other words

```
mov eax, [ptr4]
```

means "Load 4 bytes at the address `ptr4` into the `eax` register." But `ptr4` is the label for a memory address, so even if you forget to use the square brackets and write

```
mov eax, ptr4
```

MASM will auto-insert the brackets. Both lines mean the same thing: "Load 4 bytes at the address `ptr4` into the `eax` register."

MASM does not perform this auto-insertion for register parameters, however:

```
mov eax, esi ; copy the esi register to the eax register
mov eax, [esi] ; load 4 bytes at the address esi into the eax register
```

This is just a quirk of MASM that you will have to get used to.

Comment: Or use NASM, where you *always* need `[]` around memory operands. `mov eax, ptr4` in NASM is the same as `mov eax, OFFSET ptr4` in MASM.